# Using parameter for continuous assignment in verilog?

Tags: verilog, parameterized

Can you use a parameter value for assignment in verilog? Can I somehow define the width of a parameter variable?

Ex:

```
module mymodule #(parameter type =2)
    (...
    output [(3+type)-1:0] out);
    wire [2:0] rate;
    ...
    assign out = {rate, {1'b0{type}} };
endmodule
```

Lets just say type=2. Then I would want out to be of bit-length 5. rate is still of bit-length 3 (lets just say it is 3'b100), when I assign out I want it to be 100 000.

Similarly if type=6. Then I would want out to be of bit-length 9. rate is still of bit-length 3 (again lets say its 3'b100), when I assign out I want it to be 100 000000.

I don't get any syntax errors but when I try to simulate it I get:
"error: Concatenation operand "type" has indefinite width"

How would you guys approach a design problem like this one?

Answer (score 4):

You have the repetition operator backward. Should be

`{type{1'b0}}`, not `{1'b0{type}}`

I'm surprised you don't see any syntax error from that.